# Should I still use smart pointers if only std::auto_ptr i available?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

The project that I'm currently working on uses an older compiler that does not support C++11, so no unique_ptr or shared_ptr is available.

Should I use the now deprecated auto_ptr instead or should I just drop using smart pointers altogether?

Comment: If you decide to use `std::auto_ptr` make sure you understand why the issues with it.  One example: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/042.htm

Comment: i would still use auto_ptrs instead, if the system is already using it.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554162/is-there-any-reason-to-use-auto-ptr)

Comment: You can still use RAII techniques to manage memory, and follow good practices like "a class should either own exactly one resource, xor perform some functionality". `auto_ptr` will work, just be extra careful and understand its limitations. There isn't really a way to create a good "single owner" smart pointer before move semantics, but there are plenty of libraries providing shared pointers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can use Boost, it [has provided](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html) `shared_ptr` since long before it was standardized in C++11, so a suitably old version of Boost should be able to provide this in an '03-compatible way.

Comment: Would this be as simple as including a single .h file in my project or would it mean importing a larger part of the boost library?

Comment: And failing Boost, writing your own smart pointer is not exactly rocket science either...

Comment: @cmaster: `std::unique_ptr` is hard prior to C++11. A non-intrusive shared pointer is simpler.

Comment: @Q-bertsuit SmartPtr does depend on other parts of Boost (asserts etc.), but I *think* it's all header-only components.

Comment: @Leushenko It is most definitely header-only. Very few parts of Boost are not.

Comment: I imported boost::scoped_ptr into my project, it was really straight forward. 5 files including scopet_ptr.hpp was needed.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend you move away from `std::auto_ptr` as it's scheduled for deprecation.

But I would shy away from using bare pointers.

Pre C++11, you could use the smart pointer classes available in Boost (www.boost.org). Failing that, you could roll your own versions with a view to removing them once they are available in your standard library. Note that `std::shared_ptr` is easier to implement than `std::unique_ptr`, in the latter case I believe you'd have to give up portability since it requires *move semantics* to implement correctly.

Comment: downvoters should leave a comment here so that we know why its been downvoted.. it seems a perfect answer to me 0.0

Comment: @RichardCritten: Formally yes, but we are relaxing portability here.

Comment: I don't think it's about portability. AFAIK, C++03 has no way to distinguish between an rvalue and an lvalue, which is needed for implementing transferable unique ownership. If you have a way around that limitation, it would be a good idea to include that in the answer.

Comment: @Angew: I'll have a look through some of the old StlPort experimental stuff if I get the time, particularly if the OP comes back and says it would be useful to have `unique_ptr` functionality prior to C++11. I also think that Boost were working on something similar.

Comment: @Bathsheba IIRR, Boost has `scoped_ptr` which is non-assignable, and then `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Angew: Yes, that's my recollection too, but I think they were working on a unique style pointer in the early 2000s. May well have been dreaming though.

Comment: @all sorry, had the last bit the wrong way round. It's unique_ptr that's the trickly one to implement pre C++11.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `std::tr1::shared_ptr`.

tr1: 
[C++ Technical Report 1 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1)

Comment: Might be worth explaining what `tr1` is in your answer.

Comment: I don't believe I have tr1 at my disposal either, but thanks!